# coprime elements

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory, ideals

Let $R$ be a ring, then two elements $I,J$ are coprime, if $RJ+RI=R$ or in other words, if there exist $r_1,r_2 \in R$ such that $r_1I+r_2J=u$, where $u$ is a unitity in $R$.

Now let $\mathbb{Q}$ be the rationals and $\mathbb{Q}[b^{\pm}]$ the ring of polynomials in $b$. Given two elemts $I=-(1+qb^{-1})$ and $J=q(1-bq)$, where $q \in \mathbb{Q}$ with $q^2\neq 1$. I need those elements to be coprime in  $\mathbb{Q}[b^{\pm}]$.

Comment: Work on instead $-bI=b+q$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $q=0$ then $I=-1$ and you are done, so let's concentrate on $q\neq 0$. If two polynomials $f$, $g$ are coprime in $\mathbb{Q}\left[b^{\pm}\right]$ and $r,s\in\mathbb{Q}/\left\{ 0\right\} $ then $rf$ and $sg$ are coprime as well.

$I=-q\left(q^{-1}+b^{-1}\right)$ and  $J=-q^{2}\left(-q^{-1}+b\right)$.
So it is enough to prove that $r+b^{-1}$ and $-r+b$ are coprime
for $r=q^{-1}$. Note that: $b\left(r+b^{-1}\right)-r\left(-r+b\right)=1+r^{2}$ where $1+r^2$ is a unit.

I don't understand why the restriction $q^{2}\neq1$ has been given. It would have made sense if it was to be shown that $r+b$ and $r+b^{-1}$ are coprime. In that case we would end up with $b\left(r+b^{-1}\right)-r\left(r+b\right)=1-r^{2}$ and $1-r^2=1-q^{-2}=0$ if $q^2=1$.